# First time run configuration (ASP MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a simple MVC CMS for which I need a first time run configuration (to set up the database and admin user account, etc.).

The setup screen will ask them for the database connection string, so at first run, there is no knowledge of a database store.

How would I detect that this is the first time the application is being run, and take them to that setup screen?

Should I put a setting in the web.config with an initial value of false:

```
<add key="SetupComplete" value="false" />
```

And once the setup is complete, I can change it via:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("SetupComplete", "True");
```

The downfall of this method is that, if the application is restarted, the config value will default to "false". What is a good solution to this problem?

Comment: how are you planning to store the db connection string then?

Comment: Web.config is for static configuration. If you need dynamic configuration you should use some other file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Many PHP CMS doing the same thing you want to do, as it is the initial setup it would be OK that the admin change this value manually or you simply check the existence of a file which must be deleted manually.
As it is IIS app I would build a deployment package, so you can setup the the initial settings during the installation process, which is the common way for IIS apps I think.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I implemented a custom [SettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) (an example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181001%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/dotnet2customsettingsprovider.htm)). Special care was taken regarding security, ensuring keys are encrypted. The samples isn't perfect. You can use the [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx) provided by Visual Studio and .NET 2.0 to store settings in the format (e.g. xml) and location of your choosing (e.g. AppData).

It is a tad more secure than allowing your application to modify your web.config, since doing the latter means you have to elevate the privileges of your process which may be rather dangerous when your application is exposed on the internet.

It also simplify backups and upgrades.